# How can I connect between two dropDownList in separate pages in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, drop-down-menu, webforms

for example if I have a dropDownList in the first page that user should select from two Vegetables or fruits .. and then click button to next page that also has two dropDownlist

TYPE and Scientific name

...

so if the user select fruit the second page the user should select from the fruits type only >> so it should show the fruit type only and its Scientific name And vice versa.

how can I do It??

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value of the first dropdown in session or simply pass it as query string to the second page on the click of NEXT button.
Something like

```
     Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx?Val1="+ddl1.SelectedValue);
```

And use based on this value load the dropdown in the second page.
Like

```
string page1ddlValue=Request.QueryString["Val1"];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx?Val1="+dropdown.SelectedValue);
```

on page:-

```
DropDown1.selectedvalue=Request.QueryString["Val1"];
```